# apple compose email screen

Tags: ios5

I'm making an application that allows users to send messages to one another. I'd like to make a screen similar to the Apple compose mail screen. I'd like to have the scrollable text fields when trying to scroll up the compose text box.

I tried to create a `UITableView` with different cells of `UITextFields` but this is not working the way Apple created theirs, and the scrolling of the message view is not working the way it should.

Is there any sample good available? Or any idea how Apple created the compose screen? Thanks for any help, I tried researching this and could not find any information on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three20 is a open source Objective-C library used by dozens of well-known brands in the App Store, including Facebook, Posterous, Pulse, Meetup.com, and SCVNGR. Three20 provides powerful view controllers such as the Launcher, the popular Photo Browser, and internet-aware tables.
The library is modular, meaning you choose which elements of the library to include in your app. This modular design allows Three20 to be one of the only Objective-C frameworks that encourages what are called 'extensions' from the community.
You can explore some features of Three20 using the playable demo on the right.